# How can I index match unique values?

Tags: excel

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332533/add-calculated-column-in-pivot-table-based-on-other-columns-in-the-same-pivot-ta) a few hours ago and now I'm trying a different approach on the same issue.

I want to get the largets numbers from a table and the corresponding description.

[image]

The selected cell has the formula `=LARGEST(S:S,1)`, `=LARGEST(S:S,2)` and so on...
The issue is that 4 and 5 is the exact same value which makes my INDEX MATCH formula (`=INDEX(P:P,MATCH(U5,S:S,0))` U5 is selected cell) in the cell adjacent to the selected cell find the same product twice.
But if we look in the table to the right which is a copy paste values so that it can be sorted, 4 and 5th largest values are not the same product.

Can I somehow change the index match formula to the n-th of the same value so that it's "correct"?

Comment: Search top 5 or top 10 on here - I posted an answer to this a while back...

Comment: use FILTER() function with Largest if you have Excel 365.

Comment: As workaround: Give your calculated "from here" column a header. Than insert a new Pivot with datarange of the old pivot + the calculated column ;-)  ... Pivot on Pivot . Btw are you sure that you calculate the average "Alder" correct, is it weighted? (I don't know the data-source)

Comment: Not sure if it's 365. I tried to do a pivot on pivot but I could not get that working since the table that is the base table to a pivot has to be oriented the other way around. Regards to average.. well it seems correct. We have 264 pallets of apples and the sum of the age of all those pallets is 653 days. 653/264 is about 2.47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem.  You must remove ties so your `INDEX(MATCH())` can find all the matches.  Consider:

[image]

Note the both Patricia and Mary have the same scores.  In **C2** enter:

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$11,0)+COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1
```

[image]

and copy downwards.  Column **C** tracks column **A**, but has no ties! *(a simple sequential list with no duplicates or gaps)*

Finally in **E2** and **F2** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$C$2:$C$11,0))
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$C$2:$C$11,0))
```

and copy these downwards.

[image]